# Why aren't my iframes displaying properly? (blank box except first iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, element-ui

I have an iframe (table) that displays several tickets along with its relevant information. When we hover over the an individual ticket, another iframe should display ON TOP of the table-iframe that will go more in depth into the ticket that we're hovering over.

**Information about the iframe**

```
<iframe id="ifrm1" style="position: fixed; width: 75%; height: 60%; z-index:100" name="ifrm1" src="about:blank"/>
```

```
#ifrm1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Information about the table**

For the table I'm using an element-ui table

```
@cell-mouse-enter="iFrameDisplay"
```

```
iFrameDisplay(row, column, cell, event) {
      if (!row.key.includes('NCS')) {
        return
      }
      document.getElementById('ifrm1').src = 'https://rmtools.nakisa.com:8081/#/iframesla?' + row.key
      console.log(document.getElementById('ifrm1').src)
    }
```

It is worth noting, that the console.log always prints out the proper iframe url, despite the iframes not showing properly.

In the following screenshots, we have two tickets in our iframe-table.

The first ticket **always** works and displays the iframe properly.
[image: iframe displaying properly for the first ticket]

However, the second ticket (and any other ticket that isn't the first one) won't display the iframe, instead we get a blank box.

[image: iframe not displaying for the second ticket]

I've looked into this, and one of the reasons why an iframe shows up like this and when the iframe is only allowed to display in a particular website. However, this is not the case since the first ticket display its iframe properly.

Another reason could be that the url isn't being changed properly by iFrameDisplay method, however if this were the case, then the console.logs wouldn't be printing the wanted iframe url.

This might simply be an issue with css, but then I don't understand why the first iframe would work and the others wouldn't.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you aren't removing the old popup and only hiding it, yet you create a new one every time and since the old one is still in the DOM, the ID selector will change the source of the old one instead of the new one? Please use a debugger to step through your code and test all your assumptions - that your variables refer to the right elements and so on.

Comment: You may be right about the old iframe not getting removed. I've set it so that the iframe is by default on display:none and when we hover, we have display: block, I still have the same issue so maybe I'm not doing it right. I've debugged through it and have confirmed my initial assumptions.

Comment: I've confirmed that this was an issue with css, in particular, the opacity